# NXP Pico i.MX7D Device not detected in MacOS

Tags: android-things

Following this setup guide: https://developer.android.com/things/hardware/imx7d.html

I am using USB Type-C cable to connect the board and the computer. The computer is using MacOS.

I am unable to flash a default image into the device and throwing the below error:

```
Looking for devices... This can take up to 3 minutes.
No device has been detected. Is your device correctly plugged in?
If it is already connected, try disconnecting it, then reconnecting it again.
Error: could not prepare device: no device was found: timed out
Stopping adb server...
Stopped adb server..
```

Can someone help in providing details for the reason it is failing to detect?

Comment: there is an issue where your mac laptop usb isn't powerful enough to run the board, try using a powered usb hub

Comment: @Blundell I have Mac 2015 model. It does have USB mini B slot instead of C. Is it still not powerful enough? Can you provide some link to cheap options of powered USB hub?

Comment: What version of MacOS do you have on your machine?

Comment: @Devunwired Currently, MacOS Sierra v10.12.6

Answer (score 3):

I went through the same problem . I disconnected the touch screen , rainbow hat etc and then tried it worked for me. Also it is sometimes like the cable is not connected properly which may cause the issue . Once the cable is connected you will get a green light on the board . Also in case of windows 7 you may have some missing drivers .

Comment: But, it is just a hack around. How to use the peripherals without laptop power source? In Windows, it worked smoothly in a thinkpad laptop.

Answer (score 0):

> **Disconnect all your add on devices** including LCD Screen/Touch Screen, camera, rainbow hat everything.
>
> **and then redo the process**
>   It will Work !!

Answer (score 0):

FYI I just had this problem, it was the USB hub! :)